# Filtering "2D" Array of Custom Objects in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, object

So my goal is to make a search bar for my tableView. My data is a 2D array of objects, "GiftData". It's a very simple object, it's only two properties are "gift:" and "picture:" and I only want to search by "gift:" which is just a string. 
The reason it is a 2D array is because I am using a separate array of sections to divide the tableView.
Onto the problem, I cannot for the life of me get this filtering code to compile, please help.
GIFT DATA Object:

```
class GiftData {

var gift = ""
var picture: UIImage

init (gift: String, picture: UIImage) {
    self.gift = gift
    self.picture = picture

}

func match (search: String) -> Bool {
    return (gift.caseInsensitiveCompare(search) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame)
}

static func createData () -> [[GiftData]] {
    return [[GiftData(gift: "necklace", picture: UIImage(named: "heart-emoji-png-2")!)], [GiftData(gift: "tie", picture: UIImage(named: "Hugging_Face_Emoji_2028ce8b-c213-4d45-94aa-21e1a0842b4d_large")!)], [GiftData(gift: "cane", picture: UIImage(named: "ios_emoji_kissing_face_with_closed_eyes")!)],  [GiftData(gift: "shoes", picture: UIImage(named: "Nerd_with_Glasses_Emoji")!)]]
}
```

Filtering code:

```
extension SecondViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchDisplayDelegate {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterForSearch(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
}
func filterForSearch (searchText: String) {
    giftResults = giftData.filter{(dataArray: [GiftData]) -> Bool in
        return dataArray.filter({(gift) -> Bool in
            return gift.match(search: searchText)})
    }
        giftTableView.reloadData()
}
```

It says "Cannot invoke filter with an argument list of type '((GiftData) throws Bool)'.
After toying around for hours, I just can't seem to understand what I'm dealing with here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
func filterForSearch (searchText: String) {
    giftResults = giftData.filter{(dataArray: [GiftData]) -> Bool in
        return dataArray.filter({(gift) -> Bool in
            return gift.match(search: searchText)})
    }
        giftTableView.reloadData()
}
```

So, you are filtering arrays of string. You should return **Bool** value in first `filter{` closure, but you return **GiftData** which is a result of second(internal) `filter{` closure

If **giftResults** is **[[GiftData]]**:

```
func filterForSearch (searchText: String) {
    giftResults = giftData.map{
        return $0.filter({(gift) -> Bool in
            return gift.match(search: searchText)})
    }
    giftTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It still gives the error and points to the .filter function. "cannot invoke filter with an argument list of type '((GiftData) throws -> Bool)'.
Also, "giftResults" is an empty 2d array to hold the filtered results. giftData is a 2d array returned by the "create data()" function. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please, take a look for my answer one more time. You could use "map" to filter one 2D array to another

Comment: Oh my God you're a wizard. IT WORKS!! THANKS SO MUCH! This function is a total nightmare...

Comment: you are welcome
Also,
 as I understood, you are using **giftResults** as data-source for table view. And each element is presented in special section and row. If you don't want to have some empty sections after filtering, just filter **giftResults** one more time before table reloading like this:
giftResults = giftResults.filter { $0.count > 0 }